# Comparing an Array with an Objects' Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures

I am new to JavaScript and wondering how can I compare an array with another array consists of JavaScript objects.

1. The array is a series of sorted time in the "YYYY-MM-DD" format.
2. The array of objects missed some price values of several days.
3. I want to find the missed value and assign it as "NULL".

For example, I have an array as:

```
array = ['2014-10-09','2014-10-10','2014-10-11','2014-10-12'];
```

and an array with objects as:

```
objArray = [{
    date:"2014-10-09",
    price:"100"
},
{
    date:"2014-10-10",
    price:"99"
},
{
    date:"2014-10-12",
    price:"102"
}];
```

I want to get the price array in this way:

```
priceResult = [100, 99, "NULL", 102];
```

What would be the most efficient way without using other libraries? I wanted to see if anyone had a more elegant solution. I deeply appreciate your help.

Comment: more explanation required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lodash is the best library for this. But you did say "without using other libraries", so you will need to do it natively.

The *easiest* way to do it is nested for loops:

```
var i, j, d, res = [];
for (i=0; i<dateArray.length; i++) {
  d = dateArray[i];
  for (j=0; j<objArray.length; j++) {
    if (objArray[j] && objArray[j].date && objArray[j].date === d) {
       res.push(objArray[j].price);
       j = objArray.length; // don't waste energy searching any more, since we found it
    }
  }
}
// res now contains all you wanted
```

If objArray is really big, and you don't want to search it multiple times, then you could turn it into an object indexed by date:

```
var i, obj = {}, d, res = [];
for (i=0; i<objArray.length; i++) {
  if (objArray[i] && objArray[i].date) {
    obj[objArray[i].date] = objArray[i];
  }
}
for (i=0; i<dateArray.length; i++) {
  d = dateArray[i];
  res.push(obj[d] ? obj[d].price : null : null);
}
// res now contains all you wanted
```

Comment: Thank you with your solution! I will learn "lodash" later on.:)

Comment: For the second method, the last command of the second "FOR" loop can be changed into: res.push(obj[d] ? parseInt(obj[d].price, 10) || "NULL" : "NULL");

Answer (score 1):

You can create a lookup set from the object array, then you can use that to translate the dates to prices.

This scales well, as it is an O(n+m) solution rather than the O(n*m) solution that you get if you use a loop in a loop to find the prices.

```js
var array = ['2014-10-09','2014-10-10','2014-10-11','2014-10-12'];
var objArray = [{ date:"2014-10-09", model:"A", price:"100" },{ date:"2014-10-10", model:"A", price:"99" },{ date:"2014-10-12", model:"A", price:"102" }];

var lookup = {};
for (var i = 0; i < objArray.length; i++) {
  lookup[objArray[i].date] = parseInt(objArray[i].price, 10);
}

var priceResult = [];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (lookup.hasOwnProperty(array[i])) {
    priceResult.push(lookup[array[i]]);
  } else {
    priceResult.push('NULL');
  }
}

// output result in StackOverflow snippet
document.write(JSON.stringify(priceResult));
```

Note: Instead of the string `'NULL'` you might want to use the value `null` instead, as it is generally easier to handle.

Answer (score 0):

*(I'm going to call your first array `dates` rather than `array`, to avoid confusion.)*

There are basically two options:

1. Loop through your `dates` array and, for each entry, loop through the `objArray` looking for a match, and when found add to your `priceResult` array, or
2. Build a map from your `objArray, then loop through your`dates`array once, building the`priceResult` array.

#### Looping and Looping

You can loop through your `dates` array using `forEach`, and you can use `Array#some` to find out whether your `objArray` contains the date and add to `priceResult` if so (it's an ES5 feature, but you can polyfill it for really old browsers):

```
var priceResult = [];
dates.forEach(function(date) {
    objArray.some(function(object) {
        if (object.date == date) {
            priceResult.push(object.price);
            return true;
        }
    });
});
```

`Array#some` keeps looping until you return `true`, which is why we do that when we find the firs tmatch. That's why I say this is "looping and looping," even though **we** only write one loop, the other is within `Array#some`.

```js
var dates = ['2014-10-09', '2014-10-10', '2014-10-11', '2014-10-12'];

var objArray = [
  {
    date: "2014-10-09",
    model: "A",
    price: "100"
  },
  {
    date: "2014-10-10",
    model: "A",
    price: "99"
  },
  {
    date: "2014-10-12",
    model: "A",
    price: "102"
  }
];

// Do it
var priceResult = [];
dates.forEach(function(date) {
  objArray.some(function(object) {
    if (object.date == date) {
      priceResult.push(object.price);
      return true;
    }
  });
});
snippet.log(priceResult.join(", "));
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

#### Mapping and Looping

First, create a map of prices by date:

```
var prices = {};
objArray.forEach(function(object) {
    prices[object.date] = object.price;
});
```

...then create your results:

```
var priceResult = [];
dates.forEach(function(date) {
    if (prices.hasOwnProperty(date)) {
        priceResult.push(prices[date]);
    }
});
```

```js
var dates = ['2014-10-09', '2014-10-10', '2014-10-11', '2014-10-12'];

var objArray = [
  {
    date: "2014-10-09",
    model: "A",
    price: "100"
  },
  {
    date: "2014-10-10",
    model: "A",
    price: "99"
  },
  {
    date: "2014-10-12",
    model: "A",
    price: "102"
  }
];

// Create the map
var prices = {};
objArray.forEach(function(object) {
  prices[object.date] = object.price;
});

// Create your results:
var priceResult = [];
dates.forEach(function(date) {
  if (prices.hasOwnProperty(date)) {
    priceResult.push(prices[date]);
  }
});

// Show them
snippet.log(priceResult.join(", "));
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var temp[] 

temp= jQuery.grep(objArray , function (n, i)

 { 
    for(j=0;j<dateArray.lenght+j++ )
        if( n.date === dateArray[j])
            return n.price;
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop trough the object and search for the date in your array

```
// Add contains to array proto: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-array-contains/
var priceResult = [];
for(var i in objArray) {
    if(dateArray.contains(objArray[i].date)) priceResult.push(objArray[i].date));
}
console.log('matches:', priceResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will give you map of all individual arrays in your object array

```
function getArrayMap(array) {
    var map={}
    for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        var o = array[i];
        for(var k in o){
            if(!map[k]){
                map[k]=[];
            }
            map[k].push(o[k]);
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

you can use it like -

```
var map = getArrayMap(objArray);

console.log(map["date"]);//date array
console.log(map["price"]);//price array
console.log(map["model"]);//model array
```

Answer (score 0):

If i am understanding your question correctly, for all the values in array, you want to check the objArr and find the price for each date, and if not found u want to inset null. If this is what you want, then following will help

```
       var found= false; 
       var list=[];  
    for(var i=0; i< dateArray.length; i++)
    {
        for(var j=0; j< objArray.length; j++)
        {
            if(objArray[j].date ==  dateArray[i])
            {
            list.push(objArray[j].price);
            found =  true;
            }
        }
        if(!found)
        {
        list.push("null");
        }
        found = false;
    }

alert(list);
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dates = ['2014-10-09','2014-10-10','2014-10-11','2014-10-12'];
var objArray = [{date:"2014-10-09", model:"A", price:"100" }, {date:"2014-10-10", model:"A", price:"99" }, {date:"2014-10-12", model:"A", price:"102" }];

var val;
var priceResult = [];
for (var a in dates) {
    val = null;
    for (var b in objArray) {
        if (dates[a] == objArray[b].date) {
            val = objArray[b].price;
        }
    }
    priceResult.push(val);
}
```

```js
    var dates = ['2014-10-09', '2014-10-10', '2014-10-11', '2014-10-12'];
    var objArray = [{
      date: "2014-10-09",
      model: "A",
      price: "100"
    }, {
      date: "2014-10-10",
      model: "A",
      price: "99"
    }, {
      date: "2014-10-12",
      model: "A",
      price: "102"
    }];

    var val;
    var priceResult = [];
    for (var a in dates) {
      val = null;
      for (var b in objArray) {
        if (dates[a] == objArray[b].date) {
          val = objArray[b].price;
        }
      }
      priceResult.push(val);
    }

     // output result in StackOverflow snippet
    document.write(JSON.stringify(priceResult));
```

Comment: Thank you with your solution! This helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
dateArray = ["2014-10-09", "2014-10-10", "2014-10-11", "2014-10-12"];
function ObjectExample(date1,model,price)
{
    this.date1 = date1;
    this.model = model;
    this.price = price;
}
var objArray = [new ObjectExample("2014-10-09","A","100"), new ObjectExample("2014-10-10","A","99"), new ObjectExample("2014-10-12","A","102")];
var i = 0;
var priceDate = new Array();
var count = 0;
while(i < dateArray.length)
{
    var j = 0;
    while(j < objArray.length)
    {
        if(dateArray[i] == objArray[j].date1)
        {
             priceDate[count] = objArray[j].price;
             break;
        }
        else priceDate[count] = "NULL";
        j = j + 1;
    }
    i = i + 1;
    count++;
}
document.write(priceDate);
```